# Getting redefinitoin error when adding project as reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I work on VS2015.
I have C++ project `A` that has a few files and `MyClass.h`. It's built with `/clr` flag. 
I have another C++ console project `B` and is also built with `/clr` flag. The `B` has `B.cpp` with the following content:

```
//B.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
void main()
{
   MyClass* obj = new MyClass();
}
```

I succesfully can build project `B`. But, when I add project `A` as reference (right click->Add Reference) to project  `B`, I suddenly get `redefinition error` of a class that's definied in a file in project `A`.

How adding a reference can cause such error?

**UPDATE1**

All header files have "header guard".

**UPDATE2**

I thought `ProjectA` is console and `ProjectB` is static lib. But, it was late at night and I didn't notice that I created both `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` as console applications.

I know that I need to export MyClass if `ProjectB` is a dll so I could use it in `ProjectA`. The example maybe stupid but since I got this by mistake I still want to understand why I get the redifinition error in this case. I've uploaded the test to [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BZg0VyraWuAxhcoVyWvqQ3n8PqZaUmVF).

`ProjectA` has reference to `ProjectB`.

[image]

```
//ProjectA.cpp
#include "MyHeader.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

//ProjectB.cpp
#include "MyHeader.h"

//MyHeader.h
#pragma once
public enum class MyClass : int
{
};
```

If I remove the reference to `ProjectB` or I comment out `#include "MyHeader.h"` I do not get the redifinition error anymore.

Comment: Show the contents of `MyClass.h` - and specifically do you have a "header guard" on it?

Comment: I should have mentioned that it does have header guard on it. I've updaed my post.
But, how adding a refernce can cause the error? Why it works fine without it?

Comment: really you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: I will try to add what I can. But, how the reference can have an impact on this at all?

Comment: people who ask questions here are usually confused 2-3 layers beyond what their actual question states.   The actual problem is something you've probably never actually considered - which is why you need to post all the code, not just the part you deem important.

Comment: Do you use managed C++?

Comment: The project `A` has files with unmanaged and managed c++ files.

Comment: I've never used "add reference" function with C++ codes. I just used it in C# projects. Ususally, In C++ code, you just need to include the required headers and add additional libs.

Comment: I discovered that I accidentely created both projects as console, but I still would like to understand why I get the redifinition error. I've updated my post within **UPDATE2**. Can you guys take a look please?

Comment: `public enum class`? What's that?

Comment: It's c++/cli. But, I think it's irrelevant to my question since the same behavior  happens with native c++.

Comment: The point of adding a reference is that you can use any of the public types defined in B.  The metadata in the B assembly contains the type definitions.  So *also* using #include gives you a duplicate definition.  You don't need the #include.  That B is a console mode app does not matter, although surely unlikely to be intended, .NET does not distinguish between .dll and .exe files.